# Why is the first one cannot be executed?? and if i want to use the first one what should i add?? is it sum = (long) sum + n % 10; ? HELP MEEEEE

Tags: java, operators

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise33 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input an integer: ");
        long n = input.nextLong();
        System.out.println("The sum of the digits is: " + sumDigits(n));

    }

    public static long sumDigits(long n) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            long sum  =  sum + n % 10;
            n = n/10;
        }
        return sum;
    }
 }
```

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Exercise33 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input an integer: ");
        long n = input.nextLong();
        System.out.println("The sum of the digits is: " + sumDigits(n));

    }

    public static int sumDigits(long n) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (n != 0) {
            sum  += n % 10;
            n /=10;
        }
        return sum;
    }
 }
```

Why is the first one cannot be executed?? and if i want to use the first one what should i add?? is it sum  = (long) sum + n % 10; ? HELP MEEEEE

Comment: what do you mean 'cannot be executed'?

Comment: You have 2 `sum` variables in the first snippet? Why?

Comment: Next time, please include the exact error and locate the error line for us. Thank you.

Comment: And really, the "HELP MEEEEE" really doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at

```
public static long sumDigits(long n) {
    int sum = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        long sum  =  sum + n % 10;
        n = n/10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You have 2 variables named "sum" in the same scope.

**int sum**, **long sum**.

Answer (score 0):

Why you have `sum` deklaret with **int**? The parameter from the `sumDigits` method has the datatype **long**. So change the datatype from `sum` in the methode from **int** to **long**. Then you must declare the `sum` in the while no more.
I hope this is what you searching for, otherwise you must ask your question more clearly where the problem is...

**First Example:**

```
public static long sumDigits(long n) {
    long sum = 0;
    while (n != 0) {
        sum  = sum + n % 10;
        n = n/10;
    }
    return sum;
}
```